# How to add link to facebook Like button

Tags: html, facebook

probably stupid question, but one of my clients wants to modify facebook Like button not just to count likes, but also open his facebook fan page. Is it possible/allowed?

I tried this, but it won't work:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick=" window.open('https://www.facebook.com/fanpage.eu/','_blank')">
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/fanpage.eu/" data-width="" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-size="large" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
</button>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook Social Plugins are blackboxes, you can only use the parameters from the docs but you cannot (and are not allowed to) change the appearance or behaviour in any other way.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer you're looking for but you can try something like that.

```
  <button>
      <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/fanpage.eu/" data-width="" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-size="large" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/fanpage.eu/">
          <i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
      </button>
```

And for using that button, you should also implement font awesome cdn.

> https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

Comment: the link will most likely be replaced by facebook

Comment: exactly, it was replaced